# How to set up correctly makefile and get the right results in this C program

Tags: c, makefile

I wrote a C code which is formed by these files: *main.c*, *kernel.c*, *funzione.c*, *funzione.h* and *struttura.h*. Here are the files:

*main.c*:

```
#include <math.h>
#include "stdio.h"

#include "struttura.h"
#include "funzione.h"

struttura o;

#include "kernel.c"

int main(void){

  pincopallo();
  return 0;
}
```

*kernel.c*

```
void pincopallo(void){  
printf("o.x=%f\n",o.x);
printf("o.y=%f\n",o.y);
}
```

*funzione.cu*

```
#include "struttura.h"

void funzione(struttura* a){
  (*a).x  = 450;
  (*a).y  = 150;
}
```

*funzione.h*

```
#include "struttura.h"
void funzione(struttura* a);
```

*struttura.h*

```
#ifndef STRUTTURA_H
#define STRUTTURA_H

typedef struct{
  float x;
  float y;  
}struttura;

#endif /* STRUTTURA_H */
```

My goal is to display the values contained inside of the *funzione.c* file (which I don't want to modify at all just as *struttura.h*). However when I compile it with the *makefile* I wrote myself, I get the following results:

```
o.x=0.000000
o.y=0.000000
```

instead of the values 450 and 150.

Here is the make file:

```
enter CC=gcc
CFLAGS=-Wall
OBJS = main.o funzione.o 

all: eseguibile

eseguibile: $(OBJS)
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS) $(OBJS) -o eseguibile -lm

main.o: main.c funzione.h struttura.h
    $(CC) -c $(CFLAGS) main.c

funzione.o: funzione.c funzione.h struttura.h
    $(CC) -c $(CFLAGS) funzione.c

clean:
    rm -rf *.o eseguibilecode here
```

(watch out for the tabs). I know for sure that the *makefile* is not completely correct: as a matter of fact, if run it the first time, it compiles all the way. However if I modify something in *kernel.c* (for example I change `printf("o.x=%f\n",o.x);` into `printf("o.x=%d\n",o.x);`) and I try to compile again, the terminal will show the following message: `make: Nothing to be done for all.` In such case I need to do `make clean` and compile again in order to get the obvious error message: 
`error: ‘struttura’ has no member named ‘z’ printf("o.x=%f\n",o.z);`

So basically my questions are 2:

- How can I get the results correctly?
- How should I modify the *makefile* so it compiles everytime I modify something in *kernel.c*

Comment: every header file needs a guard wrapper so it cannot be included more than once in any one compilation unit (source file)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`main.c` should be recompiled if `kernel.c` changes, since you `#include` kernel.c inside it, but `make` doesn't know about the dependency. You can add it to `main.o` too, like this:

```
main.o: main.c funzione.h struttura.h kernel.c
    $(CC) -c $(CFLAGS) main.c
```

Answer (score 1):

You never call the `funzione()` function. You need to call it and pass it a pointer to `o`, somewhere.

Also, you really shouldn't use `#include` on C files, only on headers.

You need to add a dependency from somewhere to `funzione.c`, so `Make` can pick that up and re-build the file when needed. Something like:

```
eseguibile: main.o funzione.o
```

Answer (score 0):

1. fix errors:

   `void funzione(struttura* a)`

is not called and values to o.x is not assigned. Call this function before calling

```
pincopallo();
```

in main.c
write like this:

```
funzione(&o);
pincopallo();
return 0;
```

2. include *.c files is not very good practice.
   *.h files used to include.
   Create kernel.h file and add into main.c and kernel.c

`#include "kernel.h"`

write into kernel.h declaration of pincopallo() :

```
void pincopallo(void);
```

Answer (score 0):

Note: including a .c file in a .c file is a very bad practice

It would be much better to organize the make file like the following

and remove the #include "kernel.c" from the main.c file

beyond the following, it would be good, especially as the projects get
larger, to also generate the dependency files
See notes at end for a method to do that.

```
name = eseguibile
CC=gcc
CFLAGS :=-Wall
LIBS := -lm

SRC := $(wildcard *.c)
OBJ := $(SRC:.c=.o)
HDR := $(wildcard *.h)

.PHONY: all clean

all: $(name)

$(name): $(OBJ)
    #
    # ======= $(name) Link Start =========
    $(CC) -o $@ $(OBJ) $(LIBS)
    # ======= $(name) Link Done ==========
    #

%.o: %.c $(HDR)
    #
    # ========= START $< TO $@ =========
    $(CC) $(CCFLAGS) -c $< -o $@ -I.
    # ========= END $< TO $@ =========
    #

clean:
    rm -rf *.o $(name)



dependency notes:  only use the following after understanding it

#
#create dependancy files -- inference rule
# (gcc has parameters that do not require the sed utility)
#
%.d: %.c
    #
    # ========= START $< TO $@ =========
    $(CC) -M $(CPPFLAGS) $< > $@.$$$$;                      \
    sed 's,\($*\)\.o[ :]*,\1.o $@ : ,g' < $@.$$$$ > $@;     \
    rm -f $@.$$$$
    # ========= END $< TO $@ =========


#
# compile the .c file into .o files using the compiler flags
# -- inference rule
#
%.o: %.c %.d makefile
    #
    # ========= START $< TO $@ =========
    $(CC) $(CCFLAGS) -c $< -o $@ -I.
    # ========= END $< TO $@ =========
    #
```

clean:
        rm -rf *.o *.d $(name)

```
# include the contents of all the .d files
# note: the .d files contain:
# <filename>.o:<filename>.c plus all the dependancies for that .c file
# I.E. the #include'd header files
# wrap with ifneg... so will not rebuild *.d files when goal is 'clean'
#
ifneq "$(MAKECMDGOALS)" "clean"
-include $(DEP)
endif
```